# HTML SELECT resizes depending on chosen option

Tags: html, css

I have this problem that took me the hole day thinking, and I can't figure out what's the matter:
I have a **SELECT** element, with options of **different sizes**,
Obviously it takes the size of the longest option by default.
**But when I choose one option or another the select box changes it's size**,
I don't know what would cause this behaviour since it's happening only in Firefox, and in all the **SELECT** elements of my app. 
Is there any **CSS** property that would make this happen?
Have you guys any idea? Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post some code please? Ideally a Fiddle / Codepen etc?

Comment: This happen maybe because you are using default width in the select...if you like to fix , just put a width (ex: width: 100px; ) in the select element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what was the problem,
Actually as it's an oldish app, I found some reset css applying this rule:

```
* {
 padding: 0;
}
```

Seems like only firefox doesn't like this, and so applying this to an  element, makes this side effect.
I resolved it giving my  tags a padding style to override the reset style.

Answer (score 2):

You need to give your `select` a set width within your stylesheet. Without this, it will behave as you describe.

```
select{
    width:200px;
}
```

Alternatively, if you want to allow it to keep resizing, but only up to a certain size, you can use `max-width` instead.

```
select{
    max-width:200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the lack of a CSS width is causing the box to size itself automatically. Try adding a CSS `width` or `min-width`.